# DB2 PureScale on Linux

Tags: db2

Searching for DB2 PureScale supported hardware, I can see that for Linux distributions only, some System X and IBM BladeCenter BladeCenter HS22 are listed.

If I try to install PuseScale on a Fujitsu hardware, will it work. will IBM support it?

Comment: I think asking IBM would give you a more actionable answer.

Comment: Also, which pureScale were you looking at? Version 9.8 or Version 10.1?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, after asking IBM we verified that DB2 10.1 PureScale feature cannot run on Fujitsu, only the hardware listed in the manual.

Maybe in future versions...